# Bank manager withdrew funds from my account without my authority can I sue her and the bank

Tags: united-states, business, banking, ohio, civil-legal-system

I deposited a large cashiers check payable to myself into my account this morning. I tried to buy eyeglasses but I only had $100.00 available in my account. I called the bank and the Mgr clms there’s a 24 hour hold, yet the rep failed to disclose that at the time of deposit. I told her I need a minimum of $1000.00 available for this whole Corona virus emergency, she flat out refused so I said ok I’ll be by later to close out all my accounts if that’s the case. 
3 hrs later she calls to ask me where I am as she’s been waiting for me and that she took the liberty of canceling my deposit and withdrawing my funds out of my account. Is this even legal, who gave her authority to access my account? What legal recourse do I have? I have disabilities can I go to the ADA

Comment: This was almost certainly disclosed when you opened the account, almost every bank holds checks for at least 24 hours after deposit. I don't know of any bank that makes the funds "immediately available". Some banks may make a portion available, but not all.

Comment: Usually a bank has the right to unilaterally close your account at any time, if they decide they are no longer interested in doing business with you.  This too is almost certainly disclosed in the deposit agreement or similar document you signed when you opened the account.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to law.SE! Unfortunately, the situation you describe is rather unclear. You write that the manager withdrew funds out of your account. What happened to these funds? Did she tell you? Also, you seem to be asking for specific legal advice, which we unfortunately cannot provide. Please read our [policy](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice) for such questions, and edit your question to be about the general legal situation, instead of about your situation.

Answer (score 5):

So, in short, the bank did what you asked them to do (close your account).

What do you think they did that might be unlawful?